# self referential ManyToMany constraint in django

Tags: django, constraints, manytomanyfield

I have

```
class MyModel:
relations = models.ManyToManyField('MyModel', related_name = 'relations_reverse')
```

I'd like to add `constraint` which will enforce
Both ends can't be the same `object`. (i.e., `myVar1 - myVar2 can be related but not myVar1 - myVar1`)

Comment: Did you try to follow Model validation here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#validating-objects overriding `Model.clean()` with the checks you like?

Comment: This might be easier to handle at the form level (regarding feedback to the user etc.)

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531065/django-apply-same-parent-constraint-to-manytomanyfield-mapping-to-self) has a similar problem with a solution.